# how to fix: sed -e 's/é/\\'{e}/g'

Tags: sed

how may I fix the following: `sed -e 's/é/\\'{e}/g'`, as to substitute `é` by `\'{e}`?

Issue is that second occurence of `'`  is seen as command delimiter;

`sed -e 's/é/\\\'{e}/g'` does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed. To replace `\'{e}` by `é`:

```
echo "\'{e}" | sed "s/\\\'{e}/é/"
```

Output:

```
é
```

Comment: thanks, but I need the other way around, to substitute `è` by `\'{e}` (I edited question, maybe it was not clear)

Comment: I got it, you just use " to delimit command: `sed -e "s/é/\\'{e}/g"`. Shame on me! Thanks for your time.